# Nginx wildcard redirect everything to https non www but subdomains goes to a specific folder?

Tags: nginx, redirect, lets-encrypt, wildcard

I just installed Let's Encrypt wildcard certificate and I want to use the non www as my standard regex for shorter server block. So I wish to do the following:

> 1. http non www ---> https non www
> 2. http www ---> https non www
> 3. https www ---> https non www
> 4. http any ---> https any to a specific folder for example /var/www/any
> 5. https any ---> https any to a specific folder for example /var/www/any

Am I doing this right? Are there too many redirections? I hope you get what I want achieve here.

Comment: what have you tried and what were the results?

Comment: @user16081-JoeT hi, i have successfully solved my problem as you can see below... but someone may edit the answer if necessary... i didn't use regex because i read somewhere avoid using if statement in nginx due to the if is evil stuff...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer already after doing some tests...

```
# case 1 & 2...

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name <domain> www.<domain>;
    return 301 https://<domain>$request_uri;
}

# case 3...

server {
    listen 443 http2 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 http2 ssl;
    server_name www.<domain>;
    ...
    return 301 https://<domain>$request_uri;
}

# the main server block...

server {
    listen 443 http2 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 http2 ssl;
    ...
}
```

For case 4 & 5, I first need to add a subdomain via CNAME record in my DNS and point it to my primary domain then create a server block with the root folder corresponding to the server_name (the subdomain) that you want.

```
server {
    ...
    server_name <subdomain>.<domain>
    root /var/www/any
    ...
}
```

Also worth mention (to avoid domain parking and domain not related to the IP) and return a "444 Connection Closed Without Response"...

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    server_name _;
    return 444;
}
```

A reference about not using regex redirection and avoid if statement: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/